# Cronómetro sencillo en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando insertar un cronómetro en un archivo php, el problema es que al cargarse la página, el tiempo comienza a correr de inmediato y los botones no son reconocidos. Este es mi código:
js

```js
var hoursLabel = document.getElementById("hours");
var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var start = document.getElementById("start");
var stop = document.getElementById("stop");
     
var totalSeconds = 0;
     
var myInterval = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
          
start.addEventListener("click", myInterval );
stop.addEventListener("click", stop);
     
function setTime() {
  ++totalSeconds;
  secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
  minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
  hoursLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/3600));
}
     
function pad(val) {
  var valString = val + "";
  if (valString.length < 2) {
    return "0" + valString;
  } else {
    return valString;
   }
}
     
function stop(){
  clearInterval(myInterval);
}
```

```html
<button id="start" >start</button> <button id="stop" >stop</button> <label id="hours">00</label>:<label id="minutes">00</label>:<label id="seconds">00</label>
```

Cabe mencionar que el archivo php está recibiendo el script porque lo comprobé anteriormente.

Answer (score 1):

Te he cambiado un par de cosas en tu código:

```js
var hoursLabel = document.getElementById("hours");
var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var start = document.getElementById("start");
var stop = document.getElementById("stop");

var totalSeconds = 0;

var myInterval;


start.addEventListener("click", startFun);
stop.addEventListener("click", stopFun);

function setTime() {
  ++totalSeconds;
  secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
  minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
  hoursLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/3600));
}

function pad(val) {
  var valString = val + "";
  if (valString.length < 2) {
    return "0" + valString;
  } else {
    return valString;
  }
}

function startFun() {
  myInterval = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
}

function stopFun(){
    clearInterval(myInterval);
}
```

```html
<button id="start" >start</button> <button id="stop" >stop</button> <label id="hours">00</label>:<label id="minutes">00</label>:<label id="seconds">00</label>
```

En primer lugar he cambiado los listeners para que ejecuten las funciones `startFun` y `stopFun`. Tu tenías duplicado el identificador `stop`: en un caso para el elemento del botón y en otro para el listener del evento. Sería esta parte de aquí:

```
start.addEventListener("click", startFun);
stop.addEventListener("click", stopFun);
```

Luego me he llevado lo que hacías para iniciar myInterval al listener `startFun` que es lo que ocurre cuando pulsas el botón, así no se ejecuta al inicio de la aplicación, se ejecuta solo si le das al botón. Sería esto:

```
function startFun() {
   myInterval = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pon la variable como una función

```
var myInterval = () => { setInterval(setTime, 1000);}
```

En lugar de

```
var myInterval = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
```